# How can I add a custom font to my shinyapp.io?

Tags: css, r, fonts, shiny

I am building a shinyapp but when publishing on shinyapp.io, my custom fonts do not seem to work anymore. I have my custom fonts installed in a fonts folder in my www dir.

You can find the topside of my code underneath. (links to the labels of widgets in the sidebarpanel). As wel as all the css links provided by my instition.

```
ui <- fluidPage(

   tags$head(   
   tags$style("label{font-family:PannoTextBold;}")
            ),
```

#

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'PannoTextBold';
src: url('fonts/PannoTextBold.eot');
src: url('fonts/PannoTextBold.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('fonts/PannoTextBold.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('fonts/PannoTextBold.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/PannoTextBold.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('fonts/PannoTextBold.svg#PannoTextBold') format('svg');
     }
```

As this font is expected on all application at my instition I would like to use these. (As a sidenote, there is only text in de sidebarpanel).

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55100069/ggplot-with-customized-font-not-showing-properly-on-shinyapps-io/55158772#55158772) help?